# How to intercept DNS queries in Windows

Tags: windows, winapi, networking, dns, kernel

I am looking into how I can intercept DNS queries in Windows,
in a way that would not necessitate a DLL to be injected into every process and one that would ideally be able to make decisions based on the process that issued the query, hence a simple DNS proxy server would not be enough.

Superficially the path a DNS query takes looks like this, 
some application calls gethostbyname from the ws2_32.dll (or DnsQuery in dnsapi.dll)

[the dll does something]

what in the end invokes something in dnsrslvr.dll that runs as a service called "Dnscache" in a svshost process this service according to TaskExplorer sends and resives UDP packets on port 53 from a DNS server

So what I would like to do is to intercept the dns query some ware before the "Dnscache" service or alternatively replace the service with an own one.

So my question is: does one of the wise people here know what happens between the public DNS query API's and the Dnscache service and where in between would be the best place to hook into?

Comment: Nothing stops apps from making their own DNS queries without having to involve system APIs to perform the actual queries on the app's behalf.

Comment: query can be done in process, without remote calls to service called "Dnscache" in a svshost process

Comment: sure you can implement your own dns client and make it access a hard coded dns server, but most applications use OS facilities to do these tasks. And this are the programs I care about.

Comment: even in case OS facilities - all can be in single process, without service call

Comment: so your are saying i should go for a local dns proxy server and thats it?

Comment: Means the query operation can be performed in a process without depending on the service, so it may not be related to the service named "Dnscache".

Comment: Did you resolve this in the end?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by [Callout Driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/network/callout-driver).
You can capture, parse and edit DNS packet in callout for FWPM_LAYER_DATAGRAM_DATA_V4.

Here is a code of FWPM_LAYER_DATAGRAM_DATA_V4 callback to get DNS query name.

```
void NTAPI
CoDatagramDataV4(
IN  const FWPS_INCOMING_VALUES* inFixedValues,
IN  const FWPS_INCOMING_METADATA_VALUES* inMetaValues,
IN  VOID*                       packet,
IN  const void*                 classifyContext,
IN  const FWPS_FILTER*          filter,
IN  UINT64                      flowContext,
OUT FWPS_CLASSIFY_OUT*          classifyOut
){
    classifyOut->actionType = FWP_ACTION_PERMIT;

    if (inFixedValues->incomingValue[FWPS_FIELD_DATAGRAM_DATA_V4_IP_PROTOCOL].value.uint8 != IPPROTO_UDP
        inFixedValues->incomingValue[FWPS_FIELD_DATAGRAM_DATA_V4_IP_REMOTE_PORT].value.uint16 != 53 ||
        inFixedValues->incomingValue[FWPS_FIELD_DATAGRAM_DATA_V4_DIRECTION].value.uint32 != FWP_DIRECTION_INBOUND)
    {
        // This can be filtered by FwpmFilterAdd in ring3.
        return;
    }
    PNET_BUFFER pNetBuffer = NET_BUFFER_LIST_FIRST_NB((PNET_BUFFER_LIST)packet);
    if (pNetBuffer == NULL)
    {
        PVOID pDataBuffer0 = ExAllocatePoolWithTag(NonPagedPool, nDataLength, TAG_NAME_CALLOUT);
        if (pDataBuffer0)
        {
            PVOID pDataBuffer = NdisGetDataBuffer(pNetBuffer, nDataLength, pDataBuffer0, 1, 0);
            if (pDataBuffer)
            {
                PCHAR  pszQuery = (PCHAR)pDataBuffer + 12/*sizeof DNS header*/;
                CHAR   szQueryName[MAX_DOMAIN_NAME_LEN] = { 0 };
                CHAR   cbLabel = pQuery[0];
                UINT32 nLen = 1;
                while (cbLabel != 0)
                {
                    for (CHAR i = 0; i < cbLabel; i++)
                    {
                        szQueryName[nLen - 1] = pszQuery[nLen]; nLen++;
                    }
                    cbLabel = pszQuery[nLen];
                    szQueryName[nLen - 1] = cbLabel != 0 ? '.' : 0;
                    nLen++;
                }
                // Here szQueryName is DNS query name such as 'www.google.com'.
            }
        }
        ExFreePoolWithTag(pDataBuffer0, 'Tsnd');
    }
}
```

And you can check the DNS structure by using wireshark like this.
[image]

Comment: it would be great to give a minimal working example

Comment: Added the example code of FWPM_LAYER_DATAGRAM_DATA_V4 callback.

Comment: Of course, that only works for UDP queries, but DNS can also use TCP, which is a required part of a DNS protocol implementations, and we now also have encrypted DNS.

Comment: @MichaelKim Is it possible to get list of Local DNS records in kernel mode similar to
ipconfig /displaydns ?